# remove/add class to parent div when child li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a div container that houses a unordered list tab menu. When I click each tab the menu content changes accordingly. It currently works nicely however I would like to change the background image of the container div that houses the ul content depending on which li is clicked.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="menu-container menu-container-starters">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" data-trigger-class="menu-container-starters">Starters Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-mains">Mains Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-drinks">Drinks Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-desserts">Desserts Content</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I have the following classes with background images assigned:
`.menu-container-starters`
`.menu-container-mains`
`.menu-container-drinks`
`.menu-container-desserts`

My JS is:

```
$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    $('.menu-container').removeClass('.menu-container-starters .menu-container-mains .menu-container-drinks .menu-container-desserts');
    $('.menu-container').addClass($(this).attr('data-trigger-class'));
});
```

Comment: It works for the most part but as I click each tab and the background changes for each tab that I click, if I go back to the original tab the background image remains as the last tab in the ul...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link of the actual code that I have created for you https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/b3v8g3by/.

I just added `id` to the div element menu-container and modified your jquery code.

Hope this will help you :)

```js
$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    $('#menu-container').removeAttr('class');
    $(this).closest('#menu-container').addClass($(this).attr('data-trigger-class'));
});
```

```css
.menu-container-starters{ background: blue; }
.menu-container-desserts{ background: red; }
.menu-container-drinks{ background: yellow; }
.menu-container-mains{ background: orange; }
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="menu-container" class="menu-container-starters">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" data-trigger-class="menu-container-starters">Starters Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-mains">Mains Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-drinks">Drinks Content</li>
  <li data-trigger-class="menu-container-desserts">Desserts Content</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why add an ID instead of just `.closest('.menu-container')` ?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does indeed work, but I think the main thing to take away from this is that the removeClass function takes the names of classes, but you are **not** supposed to add in the dot. In effect, your removeClass was not working and then you were adding another tab class to the div container after each click.

Basically, the problem can be solved using your original approach but providing the list of classes in the removeClass correctly:

```
$('.menu-container').removeClass('menu-container-starters menu-container-mains menu-container-drinks menu-container-desserts');
```

Now it will remove all classes and only add the class of the tab you clicked on.

https://jsfiddle.net/tqr10b8p/